# ZEND Framework and JQuery/AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, zend-framework

I am new to zend framework and as well as ajax. I want a specific action in my application.

Let say I have an action and its corresponding view. In that view I have multiple things like chart plotting, table making and other HTML things.

I want to only update the chart on drop drown change event without loading whole page again.

How can do this. Help me in this regard.

I searched a lot but can't find any thing useful.

**IndexContrller**

```
public homeAction(){

if($num==0){
//Chart Data Here
}
else if(num==1){
//Table Data Here
}
}
```

In short I want to update an Action portion using Ajax in ZEND Framework.

Answer (score 0):

how I have implemented Ajax submission using jQuery in Zend Framework. You have to build your form like the following.

```
$form->setAttrib('id','div_form');
$form->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
    'label' => 'Ajax Submit',
    'onclick' => "$('#div_form').load('" . "/index/home" . "', $('#div_form').serializeArray() ); return false;"
));
```

Add the submit like the one shown above.

return false;
cancels actual submission of form.

In your **IndexController.php,**

```
public function homeAction() {
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);
    //Get your form data from the params
    Zend_Debug::dump($this->_getAllParams());
    //Process data using your model and return appropriate messages.
    echo "Your form is submitted"; // here you can render your element for display graph in view
}
```

Try the above and let me know if you have any issues.

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: I am not making the form... rather I want to update the Chart only on the basis of change event.... like this...
http://www.tradingeconomics.com/pakistan/gdp

Comment: you can skip form and make simple ajax call with javascipt and load necessry javascript for chart and add it to your view files logic

Comment: use this link to render your graph or chart phtml same like list.ajax.phtml http://blog.jtclark.ca/2010/03/zend-framework-and-ajax/

Comment: @Najam-us-Saqib,it would be glad for me if u wil acpt my answer and vote up

Comment: what wrong with my answer. ? why vote down? it is real example working for me.. why vote done

Comment: I did not do that.... u can see my reputation it is less than 125 so I am unable to vote u down.....

Comment: @Najam-us-Saqib, sorry i am not pointing to you.some other has done.but have reputation to vote up if my answer is little help you